# Canceclar cuenta Google Cloud en Colombia - Cancel Google Cloud account in Colombia

Tags: google-cloud-platform

*** Spanish (Español) ***

Me llegó un correo electrónico donde titula "[Aviso legal] Se aplicarán cambios en los impuestos asociados a tu cuenta de Google Cloud en Colombia", y no puedo cancelar la cuenta de Cloud que por error inicié.

*** English (Inglesa) ***

I received an email with the title "[Legal notice] Changes will be applied to the taxes associated with your Google Cloud account in Colombia", and I cannot cancel the Cloud account that I started by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Cloud account is tied to your Google account (GMail, YouTube, etc.) and you can't close one without closing the other. What you can do, is cancel the billing subscription associated with Google Cloud which will terminate all active services, if any.

To cancel your billing subscription:

1. [Sign in to the Manage billing accounts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#close_a_billing_account) page in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select the name of the billing account you want to close.
3. In the Billing navigation menu, click Account Management.
4. At the top of the page, click cancel CLOSE BILLING ACCOUNT.